# A combinatorial triangle for the Bernoulli numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, bernoulli-numbers

*Motivation:* We informally call an infinite lower triangular matrix
$\operatorname{T}(n, k)$ of integers a *combinatorial triangle* of a sequence of integers or
rational numbers if it can be obtained from it by some simple operation
(e.g., by summation or alternating summation of the rows), in the case of a rational
sequence with an additional normalization.

For example, the triangle of the Stirling set numbers is a combinatorial triangle
for the Bell numbers, Euler's triangle (Eulerian numbers) for the factorial
numbers, or Pascal's triangle for the powers of 2.
Of course, there can be a multitude of triangles that give a combinatorial
interpretation of a sequence in this way.
Are there such triangles for the Bernoulli numbers?

*Construction:* The first-order Eulerian numbers are defined as

\begin{equation}
\left\langle n\atop k \right\rangle = (k+1) \left\langle n-1\atop k \right\rangle + (n-k) \left\langle n-1\atop k-1 \right\rangle,
\end{equation}

with boundary conditions
$\left\langle 0\atop 0 \right\rangle=1$, $\left\langle n\atop k \right\rangle =0$ for $k<0$ or $k > n$.

Further we set, for integer $0 \le k \le n$:

\begin{equation}
    \left[ n \atop k \right] = \frac{\operatorname{lcm}_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}}{\binom{n}{k}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \operatorname{T}_{n, k} = \left[ n \atop k \right]
    \left\langle n \atop k \right\rangle
\end{equation}

The first few values of the triangle $\operatorname{T}(n,k)$ are:

\begin{equation}
    \begin{matrix}
           1 \\
           1 \quad    0 \\
           2 \quad    1 \quad     0 \\
           3 \quad    4 \quad     1 \quad     0 \\
          12 \quad   33 \quad    22 \quad     3 \quad     0 \\
          10 \quad   52 \quad    66 \quad    26 \quad     2 \quad     0 \\
        \ldots
    \end{matrix}
\end{equation}

The Bernoulli numbers ($ \operatorname{B}_1 = 1/2 $) can be obtained
for $n \ge 0$ with:
\begin{equation}
    \operatorname{B}_n = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \operatorname{T}_{n,k}}
    { \operatorname{lcm}_{k=0}^n (k + 1)}.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{B}_n = \frac11,  \frac12, \frac16,  0,  -\frac{2}{60},  0, \frac{10}{420}, 0,  -\frac{84}{2520},
0,  \frac{2100}{27720},  0,  -\frac{91212}{360360}, \ldots
\end{equation}

**Which combinatorial objects does $\operatorname{T}(n,k)$ count?**

Comment: "Are there such triangles for the Bernoulli numbers?" appears not to be the main question, but a quick glance at Wikipedia turns up $$B_{n}=\sum _{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}{\frac {k!}{k+1}} \left\{ {n+1\atop k+1} \right\}$$ in terms of weighted Stirling numbers of the second kind. An identity given in [A002944](https://oeis.org/A002944) shows that your expression is equivalent to another one from Wikipedia: $$\sum_{m=0}^{n}(-1)^{m}\left\langle {n \atop m}\right\rangle {\binom {n}{m}}^{-1}=(n+1)B_{n}$$

Comment: Thank you Peter, however I'm not interested in this identity per se (I described it in a blog post more than ten years ago as one of the motivations for choosing B(1) = 1/2) or in its proof, which Ira Gessel gave here on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/328534). My concern is exactly what the request in the last line says.