# Legendary extra parameters to simplify a counting problem

Tags: co.combinatorics, soft-question, big-list

I am reading *Proofs and Confirmations*, the history behind the alternating sign matrix conjecture, regarding counting $n \times n$ alternating sign matrices.  In the introduction, it is written that the people (Mills Robbins and Rumsey) behind the ASM conjecture added an extra parameter (the position of the 1 in the first row), and by using this refined count, managed to guess a beautiful formula.

There are other examples where refining the family reveals beautiful extra structure. My current [personal favorite](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~peal/polynomials/touchardRiordan.htm) is counting crossings in perfect matchings.
$$
T_n(q) := \sum_{M \in PM(n)} q^{crossings(M)} =
 \frac{1}{(1-q)^n} \sum_{j=-n}^{n} (-1)^j q^{\frac{j(j-1)}{2}} \binom{2n}{n+j}
$$
see [A067311](https://oeis.org/A067311).
The formula on the right hand side is not that nice, but 
by refining crossings by gathering matchings according to which vertices are starting vertices, one can easily prove that 
$$
T_n(q) = \sum_{a \in Area(n)} \prod_{i=1}^n [a_i+1]_q
$$
where the sum is now over Catalan$(n)$ objects, namely area sequences of Dyck paths. This example IMHO illustrates that refining a problem can reveal nicer properties. (From this formula, one can apply general theory by Flajolet and immediately get a nice continued fraction expansion).

Another famous example would perhaps be the [recent proof of the shuffle conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.06239), which really relies on the refined conjecture (the *compositional* shuffle conjecture).

**Question:** What are some legendary examples where refining the problem made a significant impact on the solution? Your favorite example?

Comment: Certainly not legendary, but my personal favorite discovery (in particular, because it appeared to me in a dream): consider all paths with north and east steps in a fixed region delimited by two such paths.  Then there are as many paths with $b$ horizontal steps on the bottom and $t$ horizontal steps on the top boundary as there are paths with $b$ and $t$ switched, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.2206.  The crucial insight was that the multiset of $y$-coordinates of the horizontal steps  which do not lie on the boundary could be fixed.

Comment: Also not legendary, but in order to count the number of reduced decompositions of the longest element $w_0$ of $S_n$, it was necessary to compute their generating function according to descent set (http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/56.pdf).

Comment: Nt at all legendary, but here is an example of "adding extra variables"  https://mathoverflow.net/a/29179/6101

Comment: Related question: [Generalizing a problem to make it easier](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40005/generalizing-a-problem-to-make-it-easier)

Comment: the method of generating functions in general is about adding extra parameters to simplify the counting (this seems to be the most legendary example :-))

Answer (score 7):

Something like this is ubiquitous in lattice path enumeration problems, especially for problems like the enumeration of lattice paths restricted to the quarter plane (a focus of a tremendous amount of research in the past 20 years). The basic idea is that instead of studying the generating function $Q(n)$ of lattice paths of length $n$ starting from the origin, you introduce auxiliary parameters $x$ and $y$ and study the generating function $Q(n,x,y)$ of lattice paths of length $n$ starting from the origin and ending at $(x,y)$. This lets you write a functional equation satisfied by $Q(n,x,y)$. This basic idea is the starting point for the so-called "kernel method" (see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.4387) which has been tremendously successful at resolving these enumeration problems.

Comment: As mentioned in the linked paper, these auxiliary variables are sometimes called "catalytic."

Comment: The arXiv reference:  [Bousquet-Mélou and Mishna - Walks with small steps in the quarter plane](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.4387).